# In jquery How to find the radio button Value which is in the inner div while chicking on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

How to find the radio button Value in inner div while clicking on radio button

Hi i have a radio button i want to

find out the value of the radio button when clicking on that radio button in jQuery:

```
Please see here my problem http://jsfiddle.net/c857P/232/
```

Comment: there is no class "vvradiobtn" for your radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c857P/235/)**

You're missing the `class="vvradiobtn"` for your radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="VVradio" class="vvradiobtn" id="radio1" value="1">
<input type="radio" class="vvradiobtn" name="VVradio" id="radio2" value="2">
```

I see a few duplicate IDs in your DOM. I suggest to use unique IDs for your html elements.